# URL access denied in grails spring-security

Tags: grails, spring-security

Iam using spring-security-core 3.1.1 in my grails 3.2.7 application. I just want to access my projectconfiguration.gsp, for this I added the following mapping in UrlMapping

```
"/confproject"(view: '/project/projectconfiguration')
```

But it is showing as **You are not authorized to access this page**

I know this is happened because of i did not specify any access rules for this URL. So i added the following line in the application.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [ [pattern: '/confproject',    access: ['ROLE_ADMIN']] ]
```

But still iam facing the unauthorized access message.

Why the above access rule is note working?

I know that if I access the GSP through a controller and give the @Secured annotation to that controller will work fine.

But is that the only way?

**Note:** I don't want to use the interceptUrlMap method.

Comment: first, you have syntax error in static mapping -- you are missing equals sign -- use it like grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [] -- and make sure the user u use had ADMIN role. also make sure there is not another security rule before /confproject some thing like /** which will cover the /confproject too

Comment: Sorry missing = symbol was a typo, I updated the question. I'm using a user with ADMIN role and there is no rule like  /confproject some thing like /**  above my rule.

Comment: Try `/confproject/**`, as your pattern

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

UrlMappings.groovy

```
"/newsletter"(view: "/pages/newsletter")
```

application.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    ...
    [pattern: '/pages/**',  access: ['permitAll']],
    ...
]
```